# Full url path of website on shared server

Tags: webserver

my ISP is not currently resolving DNS. But I can access most websites via IP addresses, Is there a way I can access my own website on a shared server via IP? It wasn't given to me.

Like 32.36.221.54/~blablacom/ 
How can I get this without asking them for it?

Answer (score 3):

sure you can:

```
telnet <ip of your provider> 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: <name of your vhost>
```

That's it. It should spit out the text.

Of course an easiyer way would be to just **enter the ip and hostname in your `/etc/hosts` file and browse to it**. But that would be boring wouldn't it?

The path is usually the `hosts`-file under Linux under Windows it is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) (sorry it has multiple locations depending on the Windows version).

I can't comment on where you find telnet. Usually it is within the command Prompt which *should* be reachable from the start menu (I haven't used Windows in years so forgive my lack of detailed memory how telnet on windows works)

Comment: There's no host file, I'm the asker. Please I'm new to telnet can you be specific?

Comment: Click [Start] > run...
Enter "cmd" [OK]
type <ip of your provider> 80 [ENTER]
etc... (As per Server Horror instructions)

Answer (score 1):

> my ISP is not currently resolving DNS.

Did you try with Google's DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4?

> Is there a way I can access my own website on a shared server via IP?

It looks like you can't, because there may have multiple domains map to one IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the IP address with [this web tool (DNS lookup)](http://www.zoneedit.com/lookup.html). It's very likely that you can't access your site with the IP address you got from there, though. The reason is that a web server can handle many domains from the same IP address and differentiates them by the domain name used in the http query.

Comment: I have the IP address, but not the full file path